# Authorize.net Invoice ID Field Length

Tags: payment-processor, authorize.net

We are switching to Authorize.net as payment processor.  The Invoice ID in CiviCRM is 32 characters.  However, Authorize.net's Invoice Number field is only 20 characters.  The Invoice ID when passed to Authorize.net is getting truncated.  Can the Invoice ID in Civi be shortened? to 20 characters?  If so, what is the impact on existing transactions?

We are currently on Civi 4.6 but will be upgrading to 4.7 within the next 2 months. On Drupal 7.

Comment: Not a solution but we are also using authnet with civiCRM 4.7 and for online contributions we just use the 10 character "transaction ID" to match from authnet to civicrm instead. Without having much information on the use-case it seems like this might work.

Comment: I missed the transaction ID.  That is event better than the invoice number and it connects everything up.